# How to get content of an clickable element in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium3

Facing issue to read content after clicking an element in Selenium. I have tried with below code:

```
if(webElement2.isDisplayed()) {
            webElement.explicitWaitToClickElement(4,webElement);
            webElement2.click();
}

String tagContent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) 
BrowserUtilities.getDriver()).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;", webElement2);
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following:

- If webElement2 is displayed, wait for some **other** element, *webElement*, to be visible and click on webElement2;
- Grab the text on webElement2.

It can be failing because webElement2 is never displayed.

Probably, what you want is:

- If webElement2 is **not** displayed, click on webElement (not webElement2);
- Wait for webElement2 to be visible;
- Grab the text from webElement2.

OBS: I will edit this answer based on @anonygoose's request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the attributes of the `webElement2` which you are referring at your code.

```
String aa = webElement2.getAttribute("text").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided looks correct, but it might not be working as expected because the element you are trying to click might not be visible or enabled when you try to execute the `JavascriptExecutor` code to retrieve the inner text.

Here's an alternate approach that you can try to get the content of a clickable element in Selenium:

1 Click the element using `click()` method:

```
webElement2.click();
```

2 Retrieve the inner text of the element using `getText()` method:

```
String tagContent = webElement2.getText();
```

By clicking the element first, you ensure that it is visible and enabled before trying to retrieve the inner text.

If you still face issues with this approach, you can try to add a small wait before retrieving the inner text to allow the element to fully load and render on the page. You can use the `WebDriverWait` class for this purpose, like below:

```
WebElement webElement2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//yourXpath"));
webElement2.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//yourXpath")));

String tagContent = webElement2.getText();
```

The `visibilityOfElementLocated` method waits for the element to become visible on the page before continuing.

I hope this helps you to get the content of a clickable element in Selenium.